# Rest api response as JSON

Tags: .net, json, web-services, rest

I am new to dot net. I am consuming a rest api XML response in my application. Also I am sure that rest api support both XML and JSON. How can I get the JSON as rest api response?

Below is the sample code I am using to call the service

```
string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(RestServiceUri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Do you control the service that you are consuming?

Comment: No I am consuming third party service.

Comment: Show us how you are consuming and calling the service, that might give an indication to if and then how you can get a JSON response.

Comment: Here is the sample code which I am using to call the service. `string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(RestServiceUri);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
                WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the formatted code there. It is difficult to read it properly in comments

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the content type to JSON. For example:

```
request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: I already tried this and still the response header has `ContentType = application/xml`

Comment: @viki888 is there a different uri for the JSON response? Are you sure the API gives a JSON response?

Comment: Does the service itself support a response type of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you send JSON content TO server, set ContentType - header value to

```
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

If you want to receive JSON FROM, set Accept - header value

```
 request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
```